# Simple and efficient IFS and SUMIFS

Tags: excel-formula, sumifs

I have a sample attached data and I want to use SUMIFS to evaluate the data

[image]

For example, given the following criteria and multiple conditions

Class: **buz**
 Centre:    **tre**
 Unit:       **a**
 Section:   **x**

I can easily write a sumifs like so :

```
=SUMIFS(Amount,Class,buz,Centre,tre,Unit,a,Section,x)
```

However if all values of one or two ranges need to be evaluated and not just one of it like the above, (e.g I want all classes and not just `buz`) then I can combine `if` with `sumifs`

Conditions:
Class:  **all classes in the table**
Centre: **tre**
Unit:   **a**
Section:    **x**

```
=If(Class=all classes in a range,   
SUMIFS(Amount,Centre,tre,Unit,a,Section,x),
SUMIFS(Amount,Class,buz,Centre,tre,Unit,a,Section,x))
```

I'm looking for a better way to achieve the above that will be simpler and especially be fast and more efficient as `SUMIFS` tend to be slow with large datasets.

Comment: SUMIFS, is going to be your quickest solution, it is the most streamlined equation for this sort of thing.  All others will be an array type and be slower than SUMIFS.  Even VBA will be slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using a * character instead of the class would achieve what you want (return all classes) without changing the formula.

If speed is a concern, VBA can also give you faster solutions, especially if you want to compute this total for a lot of categories.

Answer (score 0):

It is much easier to do this with SUBTOTAL and filters.

Create a cell that has the SUBTOTAL formula

`=SUBTOTAL(9,Amount)`

and then apply filters to the columns.

Like so:

[image: Filtered on prod = r and loc = y]

[image: Filtered on class = b and prod = e]